# Well-defined Functions and Maximum/Minimum Values

Tags: calculus

If a function is not well-defined in a given interval, can anything be said about max/min values of the function?  For example, if we take the parabola $f(x)=x^2$ on the interval $[-1,1]$ and remove the point $(0,0)$ without assigning any other value of the function at $x=0$, what can be said about the minimum value of the function in the given interval?  In this case the function is not well-defined, so is it fair to say that we cannot know the functions minimum in the interval?  I would imagine that if $f(0)=c$ (making the function well-defined) then we could say something about a minimum with certainty.

Thanks!

Comment: the function, as it is defined, has maximum at its end points, i.e. -1 and 1

Answer (score 1):

A number $M$ is said to be an *upper bound* for a function $f$ if $f(x) \leq M$ for each $x$ in the domain of $f$.  The *supremum* or *least upper bound*, if it exists, is the smallest upper bound for $f$.  If the supremum occurs in the range of $f$, the supremum is said to be the *maximum* value of $f$.

A number $m$ is said to be a *lower bound* for a function $f$ if $f(x) \geq m$ for each $x$ in the domain of $f$.  The *infimum* or *greatest lower bound*, if it exists, is the largest lower bound for $f$.  If the infimum occurs in the range of $f$, the infimum is said to be the *minimum* value of $f$.

The function $f: [-1, 1] \to [0, 1]$ defined by $x \mapsto x^2$ has range $[0, 1]$.  The set of upper bounds for $f$ is $[1, \infty)$, so $1$ is the supremum of $f$.  Since the supremum lies in the range of $f$, $1$ is the maximum value of $f$.  The set of lower bounds for $f$ is $(-\infty, 0]$, so $0$ is the infimum of $f$.  Since the infimum lies in the range of $f$, $0$ is the minimum value of $f$.

If we eliminate $0$ from the domain of $f$, we create a new function $g: [-1, 0) \cup (0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ defined by $x \mapsto x^2$, which has range $(0, 1]$.  The set of upper bounds for $g$ is $[1, \infty)$, so $1$ is the supremum of $g$.  Since $1$ is in the range of $g$, $1$ is the maximum value of $g$.  The set of lower bounds for $g$ is $(-\infty, 0]$ since given $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a number $x$ in the domain of $g$ such that $g(x) < \epsilon$ (for instance, take $x = \epsilon$ if $0 < \epsilon < 1$).  Hence, $0$ is the infimum of $g$.  However, there does not exist an $x$ in the domain of $g$ whose square is $0$, so $0$ is not in the range of $g$.  Consequently, $g$ does not assume a minimum value.

If we define a function $h$ with domain $[-1, 1]$ such that
$$h(x) = \begin{cases}
         x^2 && \text{if $x \in [-1, 0) \cup (0, 1]$}\\
         c && \text{if $x = 0$} 
         \end{cases}
$$
then the existence of a maximum value is assured, but the existence of a minimum value depends on the value of $c$.

- If $c > 1$, the maximum value of $h$ is $c$ and the minimum value does not exist since the infimum $0$ is not in the range $(0, 1] \cup \{c\}$ of the function.
- If $c = 1$, the maximum value of the function is $1$ and the minimum does not exist since the infimum $0$ is not in the range $(0, 1]$ of the function.
- If $0 < c < 1$, the maximum value of the function is $1$ and the minimum does not exist since the infimum $0$ is not in the range $(0, 1]$ of the function.
- If $c = 0$, $h = f$, which was discussed above.
- If $c < 0$, the maximum value of the function is $1$ and the minimum value of the function is $c$.